# Problem with Inertial reference frames Rider on a merry-go-round

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, reference-frames, inertial-frames

MASS ON A ROTATION PROBLEM.
You have a playground round-about with a rider sitting on the edge.

1. The roundabout / rider just revolves at a constant tangential velocity of 1.5m per second.
2. The roundabout/ rider revolves at 1.5m per second Tan velocity, plus the roundabout also has a translation velocity of 1.5m per second along a straight long track.

The **ride experience** will be different for ride 1 and 2

Ride 1 will just have centipedal force at a constant for the rider.

Ride 2 In addition to centipedal force at a constant the rider will be accelerating and
decelerating along the track. (Rigid body rotation with translation Physics)

The ride **experience is different**, yet we have 2 lots of physics that apply, Rigid body rotation with translation physics, then inertial reference frames, if the ride is at a constant velocity along the track it is an inertial reference frame, this physics says ride 1 and 2 will be the same experience, but they are not?

Reference wheel rolling without slipping physics for a point on the wheel.

Answer (score 2):

If the round-about is inside a train and protected from the breeze. Then the experience of the the rider will be independent of the constant speed of the train. (Consider your experience inside a train or plane.)

Comment: As stated, you have the addition of acceleration along the track of the rider, See rigid body rotation with translation physics, wheel rolling without slipping physics for a point on the wheel.

Comment: You have the addition of the constant velocity of the train; the train is not accelerating.

Comment: The resultant velocity for the rider changes on ride 2,, from point to point on the rotation, (Rigid body rotation with translation physics)

Comment: The velocity changes, not the acceleration; see responses by @Chris and me.

Answer (score 1):

> Ride 1 will just have centipedal force at a constant for the rider.
>
> Ride 2 In addition to centipedal force at a constant the rider will be accelerating and decelerating along the track. (Rigid body rotation with translation Physics)

This is not correct. In fact, the acceleration of both is identical, so the experience will be the same provided there are no external cues that differ.

Let $x_1$ be the position for ride 1 and let $x_2$ be the position for ride 2. Then
based on your description we can write: $$x_1(t)=\left( r \cos(\omega t) ,r \sin(\omega t)  \right)$$  $$x_2(t) = \left( r \omega t +r \cos (t \omega ),r \sin (t \omega )\right)$$ then it is a simple matter of differentiating twice to find $$\ddot x_1(t) = \ddot x_2(t) = \left(-r \omega ^2 \cos (t \omega ),-r \omega ^2 \sin (t \omega )\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can see that the acceleration of the rider is not changed using polar coordinates. (@Dale used Cartesian coordinates.)  See the figure below.

This is as expected since there is no acceleration associated with Ride 2 moving at constant velocity.

[image]

Comment: A playground round-about rotates in a horizontal plane about a vertical axis.

Comment: Oops! I corrected my response.